# QProcess issue in executing a exe with arguments

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qprocess, qtcore

I have a issue in setting the QProcess to run executable with the arguments. The Qt code for the same is as below,

```
QString program = "C:\Setup.exe";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-uninstall";
QProcess::startDetached(program, arguments);
```

The output of this snippet is to uninstall some program. But it is not happening. Am i doing any mistake?

But if I go to cmd prompt and execute the same thing like.,

c:/> "C:/Setup.exe" -uninstall
This works perfectly.

Comment: "it is not happening" - what do you mean by this? Does it fail to launch the program, or just fail to pass the uninstall flag? What errors do you receive from connecting to the QProcess error signal?

Comment: Did you try with "C:\\Setup.exe"? Or "C:\\Setup.exe -unistall" withoug arguments?

Comment: actually the path is different. i replaced the "\" with front slash. Its working.

Comment: I assume you forgot to escape the backslash, i.e. c:\\setup.exe instead of c:\setup.exe?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two options to solve your issue.

- Use '/' for directory separators as per documentation:

  > If you always use "/", Qt will translate your paths to conform to the underlying operating system.
- Escape the backslash whenever working with file paths as string [as per an example from the documentation:](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessEnvironment)

  ```
  env.insert("TMPDIR", "C:\\MyApp\\temp"); // Add an environment variable
  env.insert("PATH", env.value("Path") + ";C:\\Bin");
  ```

Therefore, you should be writing something like this:

```
QString program = "C:/Setup.exe";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-uninstall";
QProcess::startDetached(program, arguments);
```

or this:

```
QString program = "C:\\Setup.exe";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-uninstall";
QProcess::startDetached(program, arguments);
```

In general, when facing such issues, you could always print out the error string to get more information by using the following syntax:

```
qDebug() << myProcess.errorString();
```

This, for sure, needs an instance, however.